# bat and exe to self delete

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have written a batch script which will open some websites. I've also added a countdown timer and shutdown code, but I'm wondering if there is a way I would be able to delete it when its finished opening the website and before the shutdown. But, the other problem is I've tried to use `del (filename.bat)` and with the exe extension, but that wouldn't work. The end result will be in exe so I'm looking for it to self delete but I've also been trying to make it open another batch which would then delete both but that wouldn't work either. Any ideas what I can do?

This is the code which is currently converted as .exe

```
@echo off
start "website url"
shutdown /s /t 20
```

Comment: This looks like hiding malicious actions and should IMO **not** be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste

```
echo del "%~dpnx0" ^>nul>%temp%\CleanUp.bat
%temp%\CleanUp.bat
```

at the end of your code .bat files can delete themself

Comment: it doesnt work  its when the file is in exe that i need it to delete when ive added the code the link appears but then nothing happens (also i removed the timer to make it easier to sort out)

Comment: i am mainly looking for a way for an exe to delete itself im currently writing it in batch but then converting it with advanced bat to exe converter

Comment: It's not an executable though, it's a batch file, your program is not converting anything, it's creating a self extracting file with instruction to run the batch file. It was my understanding too that these executable wrapper programs also had options to delete the extracted files after running, so even if you don't add `(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"` to the bottom of the batch file, it should still be deleted.

Comment: will this only be for batch or would it work on exe as ive used batch to exe convertor so it would become an exe file